# Python arguments- how do you use them?

Tags: python, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086368/python-arguments)

I am not a good programmer so forgive me for the dumbness in my questions.First look at this example.

```
def hi(someone):
        print 'yo ' + someone
```

now if i type in `hi('Bob')`, then it will print yo bob. But The same thing can be done here:

```
h=raw_input
print 'yo ' + h
```

This would be easier than doing `hi("bob")`. I am trying to phrase this the best way I can but it is not going well.

Question #1: What kind of things would I be able to do with the arguments that is you know useful to you.

Question #2: What happens when there is 2 arguments, e.g. `def hi(person, bird)`?