# Python arguments-are they only used for raw_inputs?

Tags: python, function, input, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086368/python-arguments)

I am new to programming and not a very good programmer. Sorry about the stupid questions. I am not advanced. What i am wondering about is that is the arguments always inputs. here is an example:

```
def add(num1, num2):
  x = num1 + num2
  return x
add(1,3)
```

most of the functions that i have sen are like this and i am starting to wonder if the arguments are just inputs.

Question number 1: What other uses are there for arguments.
Question number 2: Could you please give examples for each other thing that it can do rather that raw inputs?

The thing is , i just don't know the power of arguments