# Refer to iterator in function called in loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to use an iterator in another function in Python? Something like this:

```
def i_printer():
    print(i)

for i in range(10):
        i_printer()
```

Comment: if you pass `i` as a parameter to the function it should work

Comment: Pass it as a parameter? `i_printer(i)`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Thanks guys! When I tried it directly in the terminal it worked, but my use case is basically the same just with classes and methods, and when I had classes it did not work, but I will try to assign it as parameter

Answer (score 2):

Pass `i` as an argument. I'm using another variable name below to stress that it's not the same name

```
def printer(n):
    print(n)

for i in range(10):
    printer(i)
```

This is pretty fundamental, there are some good explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086368/function-arguments-in-python-for-example)