# How do I make a child function, remember a variable that was made in the parent function

Tags: python

e.g:

```
def Parent():
    TABLE = input('please enter a value: ')
    Child()
```

For what I want to do, `TABLE` is used in `Child()`. Whenever I type `Parent()`, i receive an error saying that `TABLE` is undefined in `Child()`.

Is it possible to make `Child()` recognize the value of `TABLE`, while keeping `TABLE = input ('please enter a value: ')` in `def Parent()`?

Comment: Maybe pass table as an argument?

Comment: "child function" isn't standard terminology. You are just using a function inside another function. In any case, the normal data is communicated between functions is to *pass objects in as arguments* and to *return objects* to communicate out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function arguments (in Python for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086368/function-arguments-in-python-for-example)

Comment: Although not a standard approach, but you can make `TABLE` a global variable by just a statement `global TABLE` at start of Child method.

Comment: @HamzaKhurshid that won't work unless `Parent` also defines `TABLE` as a global variable, in which case, `Child` need not necessarily use the `global` stement, only if `Child` is also going to assign to `TABLE`... And I think saying it is merely *non-standard* is being too generous, it would be well-known *antipattern*.